# ¿Cómo cambiar los name a inputs clonados cuando son arrays o parte de un arreglo?

Tags: javascript, html, array

Tengo el siguiente formulario que contiene inputs que se clonan a través de botones, los botones de los signos más (+) y menos (-), clonan y eliminan respectivamente los input de label “marca y valor” y el botón de agregar clona todo el conjunto incluyendo el input de label “producto”.

He colocado nombres a los inputs de tal manera que sean del tipo array, la condición es que “articulo” sea un arreglo que contenga a “marca y valor”.

```js
$(function(){
            $(document).on('click',"#agregartablauno" , function(){                
            $("#tablauno tbody tr:eq()").clone(false)
                .append('<td class="eliminartablauno"><input type="button" value="ELIMINAR"/></td>')
                .appendTo("#tablauno");         
            });

            $(document).on("click",".eliminartablauno",function(){
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            $(parent).remove();
            });

            $(this).on('click', ".agregartablados" , function(){                
            $(".tablados tbody tr:eq()").clone()
                .append('<td class="eliminartablados"><input type="button" value="-"/></td>')
                .appendTo(".tablados");         
            });

            $(document).on("click",".eliminartablados",function(){
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            $(parent).remove();
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>I</title>
    <script>
    </script>   
</head>
<body><center>
<form method="POST" action="processclon.php">    
   <table id="tablauno" align="center" >
     <tr>
       <td>
        ARTICULO <input class="nom" type="text" name="form[txtarticulo][nombre][]" size=32 />
       </td>                                         
       <td>
        <table class="tablados">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                 <td>MARCA</td>
                 <td>VALOR</td>
              </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
               <tr id="filas-base">
                  <td><input id="txtmarca" name="form[txtarticulo][txtmarca][]" type="text" /></td>
                  <td><input id="txtvalor" name="form[txtarticulo][txtvalor][]" type="text" /></td> 
               </tr>
              </tbody>
        </table> 
        <input class="agregartablados" type="button" value="+" /> 
      </td>            
    </tr>
   </table>
   <input id="agregartablauno" type="button" value="AGREGAR"> <br><br>
<input name="enviar" type="submit" value=" Enviar ">
</form>  
</center></body>
</html>
```

Al clonar el conjunto, cada input de “articulo”, tiene sus propios valores de “marca y valor”, así al recorrer el arreglo NO se imprimirá o almacenara todas las “marcas” en un solo arreglo, así como el “valor” en un solo arreglo, sino que realizara la diferenciación con respecto para cada “articulo”, la condición es que “articulo” sea un arreglo que contenga a “marca y valor”, pero cada arreglo “articulo” contiene distintos arreglos de marca y valor.
Para ello necesito que al clonar los input de “articulo” se puedan ir cambiando los nombres de estos input, para que cada “articulo” vayan en un arreglo independiente.

He intentado a traves de atributos a traves de una clase "nom" pero no se como implementarla cuando el nombre es del tipo arreglo.

```
<script>
    $(".nom").each(function(i) {
    $(this).find('input').attr('name', 'form' + i);
});
</script>
```

Por ejemplo si clonara mis inputs para este caso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

obtengo al enviar el formulario y hacer un print_r($_POST), el siguiente arreglo sin hacer ninguna diferenciacion para cada articulo, solo tres arreglos:

```
Array ( 
[form] => Array ( 
    [txtarticulo] => Array ( 
            [nombre]   => Array ( [0] => art1 [1] => art2 ) 
            [txtmarca] => Array ( [0] => mar11 [1] => mar21 [2] => mar22 ) 
            [txtvalor] => Array ( [0] => val11 [1] => val21 [2] => val22 ) ) 
                ) 
[enviar] => Enviar 
)
```

Pero lo que deseo es que al enviar el formulario, se puedan ingresar en una tabla de una BD, DIFERENCIANDO cada articulo con sus porpias marcas y valores, a cada articulo le corresponden una o varias marcas, pero cada marca si tiene un unico valor, para esto me parece que el arreglo ideal deberia quedarme de la siguiente manera.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se hasta donde sea posible que quede asi, autogenerando arreglos utilizando la notacion de corchetes, mi idea es cambiar los nombres de los inputs cada vez que se clonan.

Por consejo de [Sebastian](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/60218/sebastian) realize algunos cambios a los inputs del HTML quedandome asi:

```
<input class="nom" type="text" name="form[]" size=32 />
<input id="txtmarca" name="form[][txtmarca]" type="text" />
<input id="txtvalor" name="form[][txtvalor]" type="text" />
```

y el codigo para realizar el rrecorrido lo tengo asi:

```html
<?php
$articulo = $_REQUEST['form'];
foreach($articulo as $llave => $nom_art ) {
$nom_art1=implode(',',$nom_art);
echo "<br>".$nom_art1;
}
?>
```

pero no logro obtener o armar un arreglo diferenciado, con la condicon que expuse antes: "cada articulo tiene su(s) propia(s) marca(s) con un unico valor para cada marca(s)".

Comment: y si probas en poner los parentesis rectos antes del primer array vacios para que asigne un numero de array? form[][txtmarca][] se me ocurre no mas, por lo que te entendi debes meter en 1 array los dos array marca y valor, eso es?

Comment: No cambia en nada, al realizar un print_r($_POST); los arreglos siguen rrecorriendose independiente cada uno, nombre, marca y valor sin hacer la diferenciacion con cada articulo, la condicion es que cada articulo tiene su propio arreglo con los valores de marca y valor, por ello me parece hasta ahora que la unica forma es hacer que los inputs de articulo al clonarlos cambien de nombre, asi se haran arreglos independientes con los valores de marca y valor unicos para cada arreglo articulo.

Comment: ahi va, copia el arreglo como te sale con la los inputs como estan a verlo, lo que tu quieres lograr yo lo manejo con numeros de ID digamos, array(=>0=>Articulo=>{ array(0=>{marca,valor}),array(1=>{marca=>v_marca})}), es esta la estructura de array que estas buscando?

Comment: He editado (ver arriba) con un ejemplo como es el tipo de arreglo que quiero al enviar por el formulario y el arreglo como lo tengo ahora, se que se puede armar un arreglo a traves de indices pero no logro hacerlo, el objetivo es enviar el valor de los inputs a una BD, otra idea que tengo seria con los arreglos que tengo armar un foreach en el formulario de envio para rrecorrer el arreglo y que sea diferenciado para cada articulo.

Answer (score 0):

Deberas probar este codigo, acabo de hacer una simulacion y funciona como pretendes me parece.
coloca tus inputs asi

```
<input name="articulo[]" />
<input name="articulo[][marca]" />
<input name="articulo[][valor]" />
```

y vas a obtener

```
Array ( [0] => articulo 1 [1] => Array ( [marca] => marca1 ) [2] => Array ( [valor] => valorinput1 ) )
```

Comment: juega con los parentesis rectos, avisame a ver que tal te fue. saludos

Comment: Con tu consejo coloque los names para lo inputs asi: Para articulo <input type="text" name="form[]" />, para marca : <input type="text" name="form[][txtmarca]" /> y para valor : <input type="text" name="form[][txtvalor]" />, modificando en el archivo HTML que clona los inputs al hacer un print_r=($_POST) logre algo de lo que queria, PERO ya al rrecorrer con foreach hay problemas con los indices vacios de marca y valor, el codigo para rrecorrer este arreglo con foreach esta arriba.

Comment: no entendi mucho....... vos dentro del primer foreach va a ser para recorrer los articulos, y dentro de cada foreach debes recorrer con otro foreach las marcas y valores.... digamos, lo que podes hacer es verificar cuando el for recorre un indice que su valor este vacio no haga nada.